# How do I programmatically scroll a Xamarin Android listview?

Tags: listview, scroll, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I want to coordinate the scroll between an editor and a listview filled with checkboxes. Each checkbox should correspond to a row in the editor.

Creation all works fine but when I try to sync the scrolling, the checkboxes scroll, but nothing past the bottom of the screen is rendered when it supposedly scrolls into view.

In order to see those items I have to touch and scroll the listView directly and manually with my finger, after which they will suddenly jump into view, but at ScrollY = 0 position.

The following code is the event handler for the editor scroll. It calls method from the Android.Widget.ListView in the ListView custom renderer I have created.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

```
private void Editor_ScrollChange(object sender, EditorExScrollChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        listView.ScrollTo(0, e.ScrollY);
    });
}
```

Comment: I did a test on xamarin android with `EditText` and `ListView`,but I  couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jessie. I've solved the problem by drawing the text boxes on the editor instead with OnDraw(). If I need to pick up this thread again, I'll post a demo. Thanks!

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for your support for xamarin. Have a nice day.  :)